# Google Sheet UpdateValuesResponse()

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I update values in Google Sheet modifyed this quiqstartfile: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php
After update i need response from google api that all is OK (it has not error). How to test that update success? How to make it?
I tried:

```
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
$test=$result->UpdateValuesResponse();
printf($test);
```

And have error:

> > PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateValuesResponse::UpdateValuesResponse() in
> >     /var/www/html/writegs.php:101 Stack trace:
> >     **> #0 {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/writegs.php on line 101**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update

According to the PHP example given there, the response you get back from the `update` is an [UpdateValuesResponse](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/UpdateValuesResponse) object.  That's not a method.

So if you're just wanting to test you got a successful response, try:

```
$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
echo '<pre>', var_export($result , true), '</pre>', "\n";

$result = json_decode($result);

$updatedCells = $result->updatedCells;
```

Comment: It is work. Thanks. Could you help me "updatedCells" value convert to variable for check please?

Comment: @Alex88 I've updated my answer, you should just be able to use `json_decode` to convert Google's JSON response into an object.

Comment: Thanks. But I have it:  `code 103 $result = json_decode($result); PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/writegs.php on line 103
105 $updatedCells = $result->updatedCells; PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/writegs.php on line 105 `

Comment: Your code: $result = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $body, $params);
echo '<pre>', var_export($result , true), '</pre>', "\n";

$result = json_decode($result);

$updatedCells = $result->updatedCells;

Comment: I have answer: "PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /v                                                                                                                                                             ar/www/html/writegs.php on line 103
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/writegs.php o                                                                                                                                                             n line 105" Could you help resolte it please?

Comment: @Alex88 Sounds like $result isn't an object.. what does `var_dump($result);` give you?

Comment: object(Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateValuesResponse)#26 (10) {
  ["spreadsheetId"]=>
  string(4) "abcd"
  ["updatedCells"]=>
  int(12)
  ["updatedColumns"]=>
  int(4)
  ["updatedDataType":protected]=>
  string(32) "Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange"
  ["updatedDataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["updatedRange"]=>
  string(17) "'Лист1'!A2:D4"
  ["updatedRows"]=>
  int(3)
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
How to updatedCells value convert to variable?

Comment: oh so it's already an object, I thought it was just a json string at this point.  So you should be able to just get rid of the `json_decode` line and refer directly to `$result->updatedCells`

Comment: I test it later. Thank you very much for help.